# How to contact a moderator on boardgamegeek.com?

Tags: board-game-geek

I created an account on boardgamegeek.com only for my account to be frozen after my first post.
While logged in, I get the message "Your user account is not permitted to perform that action." on anything I click.

How do I contact a moderator on boardgamegeek.com? The site requires me to be logged in to send a personnal message, but I'm not permitted to do so.

Comment: Surely this is a question that should be asked there, not here.

Comment: @Chenmunka, Except they are prevented from doing that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a website instead of a board or card game.

Comment: I'm a long time user on BGG. You can create a second account (a sock puppet account in BGG lingo). Then write admin "Octavian" a geekmail (email in BGG system) describing the problem with the first account. // You can also just forget about the locked account and open another since you really don't have anything invested in the first account. The quandary is why the first account got locked. // BGG has a group that very actively looks for spam. You might have bumped into that problem. For any other reason an admin would send you an email (geekmail) explaining why you are getting banned.

Comment: @MaxW Oh, thank you. I didn't want to because I thought it would be linked to my email, but I was able to create a new account with my same email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the footer of every page, there's a link to their [contactform](https://boardgamegeek.com/contactform), which doesn't require you to be logged in to use.

According to that form, you can also send an e-mail to **contact@boardgamegeek.com**.